# How do I remove a number before a section in latex

Tags: latex

`\chapter*{Chapter 2}
\section{Literature review}
\subsection{Introduction}

results:
Chapter 2
2 literature review
2.1 Introduction

I want that 2 before the literature review removed

I am expecting to get something like this:

results:
Chapter 2
literature review
2.1 Introduction`

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we can see which class you use and if you use any packages which alter the appearance of headings.

Comment: Do you want sub section gets reset when new section starts or continue?

Comment: I don't want a number to appear before that literature review

Answer (score 1):

If you add a '*' after 'section' but before '{Literature Review}', like

```
\chapter*{Chapter 2} \section*{Literature Review} \subsection{Introduction}
```

It should force LaTeX to skip over the automatic numbering scheme.